# Spring MVC web widgets

Tags: spring-mvc, widget

I am planning to create generic commenting module, that will work for any object in my application just by passing object_type, object_id.

Comment module will give list of comments along with form to enter new comment, I want to include this module in other jsp, like product jsp and others, so this should request the comment module before the o/p renders.

I know this is possible with PHP Zend framework, for those who dont understand my question properly refer 'Zend Action View Helper'

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution we need to use `<c:import url="/user/11">` this will do what I am expecting

Answer (score 0):

Spring frame work supports a number of view technologies. If your using velocity for view you can use velocity macros as view helper. And JSP and  other 'view  technologies' also have smae kind of technologies.

Comment: I am using jstl can you tell which view helper exactly supports my need